WebView shows blank screen on app restore until user interaction
I'm developing an Android app using Jetpack Compose, and I've encountered an issue with the WebView component. Specifically, when the app has been in the background for a while and is then restored, the WebView initially appears as a blank screen. It requires a user interaction, like a tap, to display the content properly. Importantly, the WebView itself does not crash or lose its state; it remains on the same page with all previous data intact.
I am utilizing the AdvancedWebView library (https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) wrapped in a Compose AndroidView. Here's the relevant part of my code:
AndroidView(
    modifier = modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
        webViewWidth = it.size.width
        webViewHeight = it.size.height
    },
    factory = { ctx ->
        AdvancedWebView(ctx).apply {
            setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) // Set background transparent for loading aesthetics
            webViewClient = this@MyActivity.webViewClient
            webChromeClient = this@MyActivity.webChromeClient
            addJavascriptInterface(webViewJsInterface, "Android")
            initSettings(this.settings)
            webView = this
            onWebView(this)
            loadUrl("https://example.com")
        }
    }
) {
    it.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(webViewWidth, webViewHeight)
    updateDarkTheme(it)
}

What could be causing the WebView to require a user tap to display its content upon restoring the app from the background?
I have tried using the 'Layout Inspector' and checking the logs to diagnose the issue, but nothing significant has surfaced that could explain the behavior. The WebView does not show any errors or unusual activity in the logs, and it appears normal in the 'Layout Inspector'.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Why are you using AdvancedWebView library, any specific reason ?

@BobSmith, it has some utility methods for file selection on the WebView, but I'm guessing I can recreate that easily! I'll try to remove it and see if this helps, thank you for the suggestion!

Hi @KevinCampos
I am experiencing the exact same issue while using the Android internal WebView. Were you able to resolve it?
One common thing in your and my implementation is that we are setting background color to the webview
webView?.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor)
